# Android: How to create tutorial at app start like in Google Analytics app?

Tags: android

In my app I want to have a tutorial when the user installs the app for the first time. I used google analytics app recently and the way they do it looks perfect to me.

[image]

I have seen such views in other apps as well. Is this some standard view or does a library exist for it? Or will I have to write it from scratch using a view pager? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I also want this!

Comment: @14bce109 That makes us two, however Downvote santa has struck again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this 3rd party library](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) is best for these types of tutorials.Here is one screen shot:

[image]

[This is another library.](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator)

[Another one is here.](https://github.com/riggaroo/MaterialIntroTutorial)

[You can also try this.](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager)

[And last one is my favourite.](https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro)

You can use [this](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#download) `ViewPageIndicator` also.

To make sure that this tutorial is shown only 1st time, you can use shared preference. sample code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String MyPrefs = "MyPrefs";
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!sp.getBoolean("first", false)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first", true);
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleCirclesDefault.class); //call your ViewPager class
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed !!

Comment: glad to here that!